# How to set up the Rails view that displays all posts with certain table value=true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

First, here's the schema for the table in reference

```
create_table "microposts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.boolean  "review",          :default => false
```

I want to create a view that allows admins to see all posts where review = true then allow the admin to either **Approve or Delete** individual posts.

**Update**
I added this into the User controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
def review
    @microposts = Micropost.where(review: true)
  end
```

Here's the review.html.erb that I have so far

```
   <% provide(:title, 'Review Shares') %>

<% if signed_in? && if current_user.admin? %>
<% @microposts.each do |mpost| %>
    <%= link_to "delete", "/micropost/#{mpost.id}", method: :delete,
                                 confirm: "You sure?",
                                 title: mpost.content %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
  <% end %>
```

How can I make it actually display the post with the option to change its "review" value to false?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to have something like this in an action in your controller

```
  @microposts = Micropost.where(review: true)
```

Then you'd could do something like:

```
  <% @microposts.each do |mpost| %>
   <%= mpost.content %>
   <%= link_to "review", "/microposts/#{mpost.id}/review" , :remote=>true %>
   <%= link_to "delete", "/microposts/#{mpost.id}", method: :delete,
                                 confirm: "Confirm delete",
                                 title: mpost.content %>
  <% end %>
```

In your routes file:

```
match "/microposts/:id/review" => "microposts#review"
```

Then in microposts_controller.rb:

```
def review
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  @micropost.review = true
  @micropost.save
  render :js=>"alert('reviewed = true');"
end
```

OR

```
def review
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  @micropost.review = true
  @micropost.save
end
```

and add the following file:

app/views/microposts/review.js.erb

And in that file put:

```
alert('reviewed = true');
```

Comment: I am able to "delete" in my view. What would be the best way to view the content of the posts with the option to change the "review" value = false though in the same view?

Comment: I'm trying to work with your updated answer, but currently I'm getting this error when I click on "review" for one of the posts in the view `Template is missing

Missing template microposts/review`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a scope

```
scope :reviewed, where(:review => true)
```

`Model.reviewed` would return all records where review is true.

```
@reviewed_microposts = Micropost.reviewed (assuming the model name is Micropost)
```

This instance variable can be iterated over in the view and displayed.

Comment: where in the controller should the `@reviewed_microposts = Micropost.reviewed` be placed?

Comment: in the action for the view. if its review action then there.